# Popup auto dismissal

Tags: python, kivy

Environment:

I have a main screen and two popups. When the button from main screen is clicked first popup will comeup. Selecting the options in the first popup and pressing the button of that popup should dismiss first popup and open the second popup. Upto here is acheived.

## multiple_popup.py

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    
    sw_switch = 'none'  
    
    def process_1(self):

        print("The process will be running here")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.sw_switch = 'over' 
    
    
    def setName(self,*args):
        FirstPopup().open() 
        
        
    def setName1(self,*args):
        self.sw_switch = 'true1' 
        SecondPopup().open()    
        
#------------------------------------
class FirstPopup(Popup):
    
    def popup1_but(self):
        self.dismiss()
        
class SecondPopup(Popup):
    
    def popup2_but(self):
        self.dismiss()
    pass
#------------------------------------

class MultPopApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_time(), 1)
        return MainScreen()
    
    def update_time(self):
        if self.root.sw_switch == 'true':
            self.root.process_1()
            
        if self.root.sw_switch == 'over':
            x = SecondPopup()
            x.popup2_but()
            self.root.sw_switch = 'none'

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MultPopApp().run()
```

## multpop.kv

```
#: kivy 1.11.0

<MainScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Options'
        on_release: root.setName(*args)

<FirstPopup>:
    title: 'Options Window'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400,370
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        Label:  
            text : "Checkbox options listed here"
        Button:
            text: "OK"
            on_press: 
                app.root.setName1(*args)
                app.root.sw_switch = 'true'
                root.popup1_but()
                        

<SecondPopup>:
    title: 'Please wait..'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400,370
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1.0,1.0
        
        Label:  
            text : "Process Initiated"
            size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
```

Now I need this second popup to auto dismiss after a background function initiated alongside this second pop. The solution in this code is which I have arrived after trying few other stuffs. Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Both python and kivy files are posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Popup - [`auto_dismiss: False`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html#kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView.auto_dismiss)

By default, `auto_dismiss` is set to `True` i.e. any click outside the popup will dismiss/close it. If you don’t want that, you can set `auto_dismiss` to `False`.

### Snippets - kv

```
<FirstPopup>:
    title: 'Options Window'
    auto_dismiss: False
```

## Second Popup - `auto_dismiss: True`

> Now I need this second popup to auto dismiss after a background
>   function initiated alongside this second pop.

### Solution

In order to be able to access the second Popup widget, do the following

- Add an import statement, `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`
- Declare a class attribute, `popup2` of type [`ObjectProperty`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) and initialized to `None`
- Assign the instantiation of `SecondPopup()` to `self.popup2`
- Open popup using `self.popup2.open()`
- You can auto dismiss the `SecondPopup()` using `self.popup2.dismiss()`. Use this either when the background function is initiated, completed or use [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to schedule a callback.

#### Snippets - py

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    popup2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    ...

    def setName1(self, *args):
        self.sw_switch = 'true1'
        self.popup2 = SecondPopup()
        self.popup2.open()
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.dismiss_popup2(), 5)

    def dismiss_popup2(self):
        print(f"\ndismiss_popup2: SecondPopup dismissed")
        self.popup2.dismiss()
```

## Note » [Kivy App - Avoid sleep() or infinite loops](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#main-loop)

> In Kivy applications, you have to avoid long/infinite loops or
>   sleeping.
>
> ```
> while True:
>     animate_something()
>     time.sleep(.10)
> ```
>
> When you run this, the program will never exit your loop, preventing
>   Kivy from doing all of the other things that need doing. As a result,
>   all you’ll see is a black window which you won’t be able to interact
>   with. Instead, you need to “schedule” your animate_something()
>   function to be called repeatedly.

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you very much. I've been through these object properties still I was not in a position to implement that in my code. Now it works like charm and I'm understanding the working of kivy properties better. 

The program is actually controlling some relays and hardware which takes around 5 secs to finish hence in my sample code I've used the sleep function. But yes, the comment regarding the long loops has been noted. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to replace `sleep(5)` and `self.sw_switch = 'over'` with `Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.set_sw_switch(), 5)` and implementing method `def set_sw_switch(self): \ self.sw_switch = 'over'`

Comment: **Message to the past from 2022:** use Kivy's builtin `asyncio` functionality to manage IO-based concurrency rather than calling either `sleep()` or `Clock.schedule_once()`. Coroutines are the way – especially now that Kivy supports coroutine scheduling out-of-the-box.